# table will be at front when boostrap date picker pops up

Tags: handsontable

[table will be at back when boostrap date picker pops up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sQBfb.png)

there fore it blocking the calendar, how do I make it always at the back?

Answer (score 0):

Try

add style to calender/date picker pop up.

```
.datepicker{
z-index: 99999 !important; 
}
```

Comment: <div class="datepicker datepicker-dropdown dropdown-menu 
 datepicker-orient-left datepicker-orient-bottom" 
style="top: 235.718765258789px; left: 730.659729003906px; z-index: 10; display: block;">

</div>

Comment: it's default as 10, how do I modify it in code actually? thanks